# Component inside of directory don't show up on production when it is one of the Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**TL;DR** - **Unable to put Component files (that render at specific `<Route />`) inside of directories, no error just doesn't render, works on localhost though**

I have the following `Test` component:

```
class Test extends React.Component{
    render(){
            return (
                <div>Test</div>
            )
    }       
}
```

And the following `App` component which has router:

```
import Test from './components/Test'

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
           <BrowserRouter>
               <Switch>
                    <Route exact
                           path="/"
                           component={Test}
                     />                
              </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

I am using react v16 and react-router v4

Everything works fine on localhost.

But when I create a build file and serve build files, I don't see `Test` component when it is in `components` directory - file location:`./components/Test`.

The solution I found was to just take `Test.js` and put it in the same directory as `App.js` and `Test` component is then rendered.

**Why am I not able to put my `Test` component into `/components` directory, any suggestions?**

**if need more details:**

PS: I am using *parcel*

relevant part from `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html --public-url ./"
  },
```

I have `index.html` along with `App.js` in `src` directory.

I checked `NODE_PATH`, it is `undefined`.

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: I am using parcel-bundler @sklingler93